# iPhone Best Way To Display Many instances Of Small Image

Tags: iphone, graphics, cocos2d-iphone, core-graphics, 2d

Im just wondering what would the best way to display multiple instances of a small (10x1) image. I have an array of about 480 points and I would like to draw the image at each of these points to draw path. Would it be faster to use Core Graphics or should I be using something like cocos2d?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether you need it to animate. Core Graphics is probably fine if you are drawing it once and then displaying it as an image, but it it will be really slow if you need to redraw it each frame.

UIKit is actually much quicker because UIView drawing is hardware accelerated, so you could just add a UIImageView for each point in the graph, but from my own experiments that will probably be too slow for realtime interaction if there is more than about 200 image views (at least if you want it to run on anything older than an iPhone 4S).

If you do need realtime performance, that really only leaves OpenGL, which is quite fiddly to set up unless you use a library like Cocos2D or Sparrow to simplify it. I'd suggest Sparrow for your purposes because Sparrow views can be used in a regular UIKit application, whereas Cocos2D provides a whole app framework and is harder to use for just a single view in an otherwise regular UIKit app.

http://www.sparrow-framework.org/

Answer (score 0):

Without more context, another option is to use OpenGL and create a display list for the composite image.